# How to have QueryDSL get a path's field type from the QClass dynamically?

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl, metamodel

QueryDSL creates for us some nice metamodel Q-classes, where the fields of those Q-classes are, whenever possible, paths of a specific type. For example, if you have an Integer field for age in your User class, the field will have a type of NumberPath in the QUser class.

Suppose I'm using QueryDSL to build up a query like

```
user.from(user).where(user.age.eq(30))
```

I'd like to be able to get user.age's path-type that exists in the QClass - that is, NumberPath.

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you sketch via pseudocode what you need? I am not sure if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Sure. So say you have a class named User, which has an Integer age in it. The generated QClass has, instead of an Integer age field, a NumberPath age field. I'd like to be able to get the type of this age field and have it return NumberPath.class.

Comment: By get you mean not accessing by field, but getting by name, something like `path.get("age")`? That's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to simply call `user.age.getClass()`?

`user.age instanceof NumerClass` should also work.

If you have the bare name as String you could use reflection:

```
user.getClass().getDeclaredField("age").getType()
```

should return `NumberPatch.class`. A bit dirty, but should work.